# XCUIElementQuery in SwiftUI testing returns inconsistent count

Tags: unit-testing, testing, swiftui

I'm doing UI testing of a SwiftUI view, and I have the following code to fetch a List element to check the count of staticTexts in it:

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "identifier == 'detailViewTable'")
let detailViewTable = app.descendants(matching: .any).matching(pred).firstMatch
let arrOfTexts = detailViewTable.staticTexts
let ct = arrOfTexts.count
print("Count is: \(ct)") // This prints 0
print("Count is now: \(detailViewTable.staticTexts.count)") // Also prints 0
```

The count always prints as 0.

The SwiftUI view basically looks like this:

```
List {
   Section(header: Text("Item list")) {
     HStack {
        Text("Number")
        Spacer()
        Text(rec.recNum)
     }
   }
// Lots more Sections/HStacks/Texts/etc here 
// ...
// ...
}
.accessibility(identifier: "detailViewTable")
.listStyle(.grouped)
```

When I put a breakpoint as shown,

[image]

and use `po` in the Debug Console, I get **0** for `ct`, but **21** if calling `count` directly:

```
(lldb) po ct
0
(lldb) po detailViewTable.staticTexts.count
21
```

Pic here:

[image]

Why is the var `ct` set to **0**, but calling the count directly gives me the correct number **21**?

It makes me wonder if the XCUIElementQuery takes a moment to run and returns the answer in some kind of implicit callback, and the data isn't ready at the moment the variable `ct` is set, but will return the correct answer in the debug console because it waits for the response. However, I don't see any discussion of a callback in the Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37320452

pointed me in the right direction. The fix is to put a pause in the form of `sleep(1)`, to give the query time to do its fetch, I assume.

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "identifier == 'detailViewTable'")
let detailViewTable = app.descendants(matching: .any).matching(pred).firstMatch
let arrOfTexts = detailViewTable.staticTexts
sleep(1) // <-- Add this
let ct = arrOfTexts.count
print("Count is: \(ct)") // Now prints 21
print("Count is now: \(detailViewTable.staticTexts.count)") // Also prints 21
```